# Accessing a struct field in adjacent to a conditional expression

Tags: c

why there is a difference between the 2 next code segments:

```
struct g {
    int m[100];
};


struct a {
    struct g ttt[40];
    struct g hhh[40];
}man;


extern int bar(int z);


//this code generate a call to memcopy.
void foo1(int idx){
    bar(((idx == 5) ? man.hhh[idx+7] : man.ttt[idx+7]).m[idx+3]);
}

//this code doesn't generate a call to memcopy.    
void foo2(int idx){
    bar(((idx == 5) ? man.hhh[idx+7].m[idx+3] : man.ttt[idx+7].m[idx+3]));
}
```

In both codes segment I want to send the same field (depends on the conditional expression) to bar function. However one the first code generate a call to memcopy (when compiled with clang to powerpc arch it can be seen clearly). I wrote a little main and run the 2 functions and they gave me the same output (compiled with gcc 4.4.7).

Comment: converting struct to int?

Comment: Please select one language tag corresponding to which language you are using

Comment: In the first snippet, the result of the conditional expression has type `struct g`. The compiler makes a copy of that result using `memcpy`. In the second snippet, the result of the conditional expression has type `int`. The compiler can make a copy of that result using a `mov` instruction. So avoid using the first snippet, the second snippet is easier to read anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to C only - the question is dual-tagged but I am assuming OP is using C for reasons that will become clear later.

---

Here's the first expression again:

```
((idx == 5) ? man.hhh[idx+7] : man.ttt[idx+7]).m[idx+3]
```

The type of the conditional expression is `struct g`. However, the result of the conditional operator in C is *not* an lvalue.  What is it then?

- In C11 6.2.4p8 it's explicitly defined as a value of temporary lifetime.
- In C90 the `m[idx+3]` is ill-formed:  `m` is not an lvalue because the `.` operator only yields an lvalue if the left operand was an lvalue; and the array-pointer decay only applies to lvalues.
- In C99 array-pointer decay happens to all values, but it's not explicitly stated where decayed `m` points.

Personally I think it's clear enough that in C99, something akin to the C11 behaviour was intended, so I would regard the code as well-defined in C99. [Further discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755628/undefined-behavior-when-attempting-to-access-the-result-of-function-call).  This is probably a moot point, as on all the compilers I tried, they gave the same result for `-std=c99` as they did for `-std=c11`.

Moving forward then: In C11 (and probably C99), Snippet 1 should give the right result. Your compiler does that, but it seems that it optimizes the code poorly. It naively copies the whole value resulting from the conditional operator before indexing into it.

Testing with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/1IIbW3), I found that all versions of "x86 clang" and "PowerPC gcc 4.8" used `memcpy`; but "x86 gcc" was able to optimize the code.

<sub>In C++, the result of the conditional operator is an lvalue if the second and third operands were lvalues of the same type, so this problem shouldn't arise in that language.</sub>

---

To avoid this problem, use an alternative where the result of the conditional operator is not a struct or union value. For example you could just use Snippet 2; or either of:

```
bar( ((idx == 5) ? &man.hhh[idx+7] : &man.ttt[idx+7]))->m[idx+3] );

bar( ((idx == 5) ? man.hhh : man.ttt)[idx+7].m[idx+3] );
```